# how do I replace the string from the top of the file with the bottom string based on pattern

Tags: string, bash, replace

I have the following file:

```
petro,36262
artur,946034
alex,12345
alex,99999
artur,111111111
```

What I need is to replace the upper strings with bottom ones based on first column as primary key, so in the end it would look like:

```
petro,36262
alex,99999
artur,111111111
```

The first column can contain a space or a number.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
$ awk -F, '{a[$1]=$2} END{for (name in a)print name","a[name]}' file
alex,99999
artur,111111111
petro,36262
```

The lines come out in arbitrary order.  If you have a preferred order, some additional code would be needed.